# Flow types in object with functions

Tags: javascript, flowtype

everyone! please, help me to solve my problem. I have object with functions where the keys is equal to type name in object with data. but I cant force flow to understand it correctly. Is there any way to annotate such cases?

```
const obj = {
  type1: func1,
  type2: func2
}

type Type1 = 'type1';
type Type2 = 'type2';

type Item1 = {
  type: Type1,
  dataInItem1: string
}

type Item2 = {
  type: Type2,
  dataInItem2: string
}
const item1: Item1 = {
  type: 'type1',
  dataInItem1: 'dataInItem1' 
}
const item2: Item2 = {
  type: 'type2',
  dataInItem2: 'dataInItem2' 
}
const getItemByPropType = (item: Item1 | Item2, obj) => {
   return obj[item.type](item)
}

Cannot call getItemByPropType with item bound to the first parameter because:
• all branches are incompatible:
• Either property dataInItem2 is missing in Item1 [1] but exists in Item2
```